# Naive Question: How to access google drive/sheets from Jupyter without downloading a service key?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-api, service-accounts, workload-identity

I'm new to Coding and APIs. Trying to learn with a small personal project and my main question is:

"
How do folks with personal projects access gsheets? Do you use service accounts and keys? If yes, where and how do you safely store these service keys? I understand they are like user passwords so I would like to store them securely. If no, how else do you access google drive/sheets?
"

My data is stored in a google sheet and I would like to access it from my Jupyter Notebook.
In google console, I setup a google project and enabled the G-Drive and G-sheet APIs.

I created a service account and when I went to manage keys I saw this message from google:

*"Service account keys could pose a security risk if compromised. We recommend you avoid downloading service account keys and instead use the Workload Identity Federation . You can learn more about the best way to authenticate service accounts on Google Cloud here ." *

Doing some reading online, I wondered if I could perhaps use tokens or other ways to access gsheets that did not recure secure storage of service account keys.

Thanks for helping and apologies in advance if this is a dumb question .